# How to get rid of the selection circles?

Tags: android, listview

I am currently attempting to use ListView in my Android Studio project.

I've attempted to implement onSelectedListener, but it kept on not selecting, so I had to use onClickListener instead.

The problem is that the circles for a selection on the list items are still there, but unused now that I use onClickListener instead of onSelect.

**How can I remove these selection circles on the list items?**

**On a related note, if possible, can you find a reason why onSelected doesn't work on my ListView?**

ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder ExceedingLimitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsMenu.this);
                //Storing Original value
                final int OriginalExceed = PhoneBelt.getExceedInt();
                //Setting ListView
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exceeding_dialog, null);
                lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SettingsMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, ExceedingSelection);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        int SelectedItem = Integer.parseInt(ExceedingSelection[position]);
                        PhoneBelt.setExceedInt(SelectedItem);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsMenu.this, "You have selected" + SelectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
                ExceedingLimitDialog.setView(convertView);
                ExceedingLimitDialog.setTitle(R.string.Exceeding_Limit_Title);
                ExceedingLimitDialog.setMessage(R.string.Exceeding_Limit_Message);
                ExceedingLimitDialog.setCancelable(true);

                AlertDialog alert = ExceedingLimitDialog.create();
                alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those selection circles are part of the `CheckedTextView` that is the sole `View` in the `simple_list_item_single_choice` layout you're currently using for the item layout in your `ListView`'s `Adapter`. If you don't want those, you can instead use a layout that is a regular `TextView`, which the `simple_list_item_1` layout is.

Simply change `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` inside `ListView`.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought the OP meant at first, too, the ripple effect. I'll guess we'll see.

Comment: No, the selection circles on the right side of the bar, not the ripple effect.